# Hint for summation is needed

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, summation, trigonometric-series

$$
  \newcommand{\arccot}{\operatorname{arccot}}
  \arccot(2)+\arccot(8)+\arccot(18)+\arccot(32)+\ldots=?
$$
this the question.
First find a relation of $2,8,18,32,\ldots$
$$
  a_1=2, a_2=8, a_3=18, a_4=32  ,\ldots 
$$
it seems the difference between them $6,10,14,\ldots\  (+4)$ so maybe $a_5=50,a_6=72 ,\ldots$
but what next?

according to OEIS, this sequence is the mean of two triangular numbers such as
$$
  \frac{1+3}{2},\frac{6+10}{2},\frac{15,21}{2},\ldots
$$
and what is the next step?

then I tried to rewrite $$
  \arccot(2)+\arccot(8)+\arccot(18)+\arccot(32)+\ldots=\\ 
  \arctan(\frac1{2})+\arctan(\frac1{8})+\arctan(\frac1{18})+
    \arctan(\frac1{32})+\ldots
$$
than find the partial sum with desmos https://www.desmos.com/calculator/k7xv7l8d8z

it seems bounded, but got no clue to solve it analytically.
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: It looks as if the arguments are of the form $2n^2$. Maybe it gives someone an idea...

Comment: It is telescopic by the arctan addition formula.

Comment: @JeroenBoschma: Thank you ...I didnot care about $2n^2$...thank you again